# Android Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So, whenever I try to launch my app on the android emulator the IDE gets bombarded with this error:

```
Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset.......
```

This error also shows when the application is running every minute or so.

I'm using

- Android Studio 3 Beta 6
- API Level 26
- Emulator 26.1.4
- Android SDK
- Tools 26.1.1
- Image x86 26 (oreo)

...

I've tried to re-install all of the SDK tools and update everything to the latest but had no luck. I also re-installed the IDE and re-downloaded everything and it still shows this error.

I'm wondering if anyone ran into this error as well?

Comment: There is a open issue in the Issue Tracker related with that [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66114788](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66114788) There isn't any fix yet

Comment: I've just filed another bug report and saw your answer. seems like it's affecting their latest image they pushed last night

Comment: @SolidSnake have you managed to find a workaround?

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin - no we can't do much it's an issue from google and they're working on it. you can just disable the popup notifications for now and ignore the error until google update the image

Comment: Emulator works just fine, but I'm experiencing exactly the same messages with Android Studio 3.0 Stable. Have you got any solution other than hide message popups in IDE settings?

Comment: It seems to have been fixed in the latest version of the emulator - 27.0.2

Answer (score 70):

I'm sure ([hope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353221/android-emulator-qemu-system-i386-exe-goldfish-battery-read-bad-offset/46375142#comment80837867_46375142)) Google will fix this bug soon, but in the meantime all the popup notifications are very annoying. For me the emulator seems to be working fine. I just wanted to temporarily disable the popup notification.

You can do that by selecting the **Settings icon** on the popup. Then choose **No popup** from the menu for **Emulator**.

[image]

I left the Log checkbox checked so that I can still monitor the Event Log.

Comment: I've already done that after few failed tries to fix the issue.

Comment: Still an issue for me in Android Studio 3.0 RC 2

Comment: still not fixed in Android Studio 3.0

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue for emulator running Oreo. Emulator won't boot up and throw message 'Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset '.

I solved it by following;

1. Launch standalone sdk manager
2. Download "Google Play Intel x86 atom Image" under API 26 (OREO)
3. Launch avd manager from sdk manager > tools > manager avds.. (not from android studio).
4. Create or edit AVD.
5. **Under CPU/ABI choose image "Google Play Intel x86 atom Image" 
   (*instead of "Google API Intel x86 atom Image"*)**
6. Start AVD. It should work.

Comment: Well, `Google Play` image works, but I get `emulator-5444 unauthorized`. `Google APIS` might work with `adb`, but this error occurs. Oh well :) .

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. It's really weird but I solve partially that changing the Emulator.ini file adding/changing:

```
hw.audioInput=no
hw.audioOutput=no
```

Answer (score 0):

Until Google fixes this for Android API 27, the following steps worked for me:

1) In SDK Manager/SDK Platforms tab/ click Show Package Details (check box on bottom right).

-Uncheck to remove all Android API 27 settings.

-Select to install Android 8.0, Android SDK Platform 26, Sources for Android 26, Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (you may NOT need the Atom_64 if you don't have a 64bit system)

2) Click SDK Tools tab then click Show Package Details (check box on bottom right).

-Under Android SDK Build-Tools, unselect to uninstall any or all 27.0.0 - 27.0.3.

-Select to install 26.0.2 (which works for me but you can select whatever other builds you want just STAY AWAY from the 27s)

3) Click Apply.

4) Execute in terminal: adb kill-server.

5) Exit to close all Android Studio.

6) In Windows Task Manager, verify or End task for adb.exe (which should already be killed), qemu-system-i386.exe.

7) Restart AS and make sure you have the following in your Gradle build file: buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

You should now be able to run your emulator without the  qemu-system-i386.exe issues.